# Teechart, Monodroid Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, teechart

I get the following stacktrace every time I try to press the Chart
(same error here: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=13740):

```
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallFloatMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00024] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.4-series/6418373f/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:319

  at Android.Views.MotionEvent.GetX (int) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.4-series/6418373f/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.Views.MotionEvent.cs:383

  at Steema.TeeChart.Chart.spacing (Android.Views.MotionEvent) <IL 0x00009, 0x00077>

  at Steema.TeeChart.Chart.CheckZoomPanning (Android.Views.MotionEvent) <IL 0x0003b, 0x00177>

  at Steema.TeeChart.Chart.DoMouseDown (bool,Android.Views.MotionEvent) <IL 0x00266, 0x00de7>

  at Steema.TeeChart.TChart.OnMouseDown (Android.Views.MotionEvent) <IL 0x00014, 0x00093>

  at Steema.TeeChart.TChart.OnTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent) <IL 0x00002, 0x0004f>

  at Steema.TeeChart.ChartImageView.Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener.OnTouch (Android.Views.View,Android.Views.MotionEvent) <IL 0x0052f, 0x0169f>

  at Android.Views.View/IOnTouchListenerInvoker.n_OnTouch_Landroid_view_View_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_ (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00018] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.4-series/6418373f/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:1201

  at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.e537c44c-b66f-45e0-8d7d-2fc23299124c (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0001d, 0x00053>
```

--- End of managed exception stack trace ---

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range

```
at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)

at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:1981)

at steema.teechart.ChartImageView.n_onTouch(Native Method)

at steema.teechart.ChartImageView.onTouch(ChartImageView.java:69)

at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7122)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)

at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)

at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)

at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)

at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)

at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)

at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)

at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)

at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)

at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)

at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3174)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3119)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4134)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4226)

at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)

at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)

at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm using the evaluation version of teechart for mono. The link at the top offers the solution but only for paying customers. Is there another way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, new registered and evaluation version installers fixing this issue (TM63016457) were [published last week](http://www.steema.com/entry/145/TeeChart_for_Xamarin.Android_4.13.03.04_maintenance_release_available). Please go to the [download area](http://www.steema.com/clientaccess) and download the new evaluation version installers (build 4.13.03.04).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a new version out. Fixed it immediately.

Comment: @wim11be you're welcome! If you want to be notified about new releases please stay tuned to our communication channels (web, blog, twitter, facebook or forums) available at www.steema.com.